# Strange text language in SNAP install via Software Center

Tags: software-center, snap, 17.04

After a upgrade to 17.04 I try to install a SNAP from the Ubuntu Software Center and after the login information for my Ubuntu One account it ask me to introduce my local admin password. But the text windows as strange text, the bold one ("Snap Yüklemek ...") that is not Italian. Why?

[image]

Comment: Uncle Google translate says is Turkish . Could you add the output of `env | grep -i lang` to the question

Comment: @user.dz the result of `env | grep -i lang` is: `LANG=it_IT.UTF-8` `GDM_LANG=it` `LANGUAGE=it:en`. My default language should be Italian.

Comment: It could be something set within the target snap package itself.