# Ubuntu in spanish giving messages in Turkish

Tags: snap, 17.04, inkscape

Updated to 17.04 (Acer Laptop, Intel Core i7, Geforce Gtx860m)
Tried to install Inkscape (had Inkscape development PPA still installed)
Was told I had to login to "Snaps Store" by Ubuntu Software. When I tried to login with Ubuntu One credentials, I got a message in Turkish.
My Ubuntu is in Spanish.
Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgvgH.jpg
Extra info, every time, still in 16.10, that it installed something via Snap, it would not open files properly, so I had to substitute new versions installed via snap with PPA's or apt-get.

Comment: Can you open a terminal, run the `locale` command, and then [edit] your question and add the output there?

Comment: Same case here https://askubuntu.com/q/906236/26246 , no answer yet

Comment: This looks like a bug perhaps in gnome-software. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+filebug